# how to properly create a Javascript semi-dynamic javascript code generator

Tags: node.js

I have a REST API layer that I need to implement. The good news is that the layer is well defined so using a JSON dataset and converting it to the corresponding API doc is easy with handlebars or Mustache, however, I also need to generate the actual handlers and register the handlers with the expressjs.

**Yes I know this is bad for client side code.**

*this is the 100% correct but demonstrates the challenge*

```
var tmpl = "app.get({{path}}, function(req, res) { ... and some work ...} )";
var all_path = [{path:'/hello',body:"function(msg) {return pub(msg);}"},{path:'/world'},];
for(var i=all_path.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    task = mustache.Render(tmpl, all_path[i]);
    eval(task);
}
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you are trying to do?  I see no reason why you would want to use `eval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `... and some work ...` is largely the same for each, with just different `path` values, you can accomplish this with just another function:

```
function addGenericGetHandler(path) {
    app.get(path, function (req, res) {
        // ... and some work ...
    });
}

[ '/hello', '/world' ].forEach(addGenericGetHandler);
```

Comment: I added a "body" tag to the sample. In the end I think I'm going to have a list of request param names, response param names, the name of the action which will be pushed onto the bus. Your approach with the lambda-esq function might work. Putting the apt.get() inside the loop did not work because variables inside the anon-function() used the last value of the global variable: body = all_path[i].body always evaluated to the last value of i.

Comment: I should add one more thing.  I'm calling apt.get() in the example, however, it's really meant to be:  apt.{{verb}}

Comment: @Richard To solve the issue with `i`, you need a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) to trap the value per-iteration. Iterators like [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)s can be used to create them. Also, since this is definitely more complex than just dynamic paths, you need to give more detail on the problem. Expand on the `... and some work ...`. Where would `body` even fit in?

Comment: @Richard Though, if you're just looking for an way to represent your routes in an object, have a look at the [`route-map` example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/route-map/index.js).

Comment: I like the route-map. It makes the code look small and more manageable, however, my reason for using the MDD-like approach was so that I could generate API documentation from the same dataset.